# Contents of ng-bind-html is not wrapped in modal

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-bind-html

When I use ng-bind-html in a modal, e.g.

```
<div ng-bind-html="verificationScript"></div>
```

... the html that is bound to the div will not be contained in the modal, it will spill over its edges. How can I prevent this?

Comment: could you elaborate more on this ?

Comment: using css `overflow` property maybe?